# Issue writing CSV using CSV module in python

Tags: python, csv

Trying to print some strings as rows into a csv however, it gets printed as a column . Code is:

```
with open('test.csv','w') as b:
a = csv.writer(b)
a.writerows(strings)
b.close()
```

Output is

```
GGKKKTKICDKVSHEEDRISQ   ISEILFHLSTKDSVRTSALST   FDSHRDSWIRKLRLDLGYHHD   HLDVHCFHDNKIPLSIYTCTT
```

I would need it as rows like:

```
GGKKKTKICDKVSHEEDRISQ

ISEILFHLSTKDSVRTSALST
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writerows` expects a list of lists - each inner list a row. I assume that `strings` is a list of strings, and thus treated like a single row. To covert it to a list of rows, which is what you want, use:

```
a.writerows([[x] for x in strings])
```

Comment: @ Korem : Thanks , It prints the rows now but output is in tabs like G G K K T K I C D K V S H ... I need it as a single string.